# I have a problem with this sentence.'Sometimes you will be asked to identify how one paragraph relates to another.'

Tags: passive-voice

Please can anyone explain why 'Sometimes you **will be asked** to..' OR 'In Factual Information questions **you are asked** what information an author has presented.' ?

Why not "Sometimes you **will be ask**" or 'In Factual Information questions **you are ask**..'????

As I know ***Asked*** is the past simple but why there is I see **will be + asked**.

Answer (score 1):

*Asked* here is a passive participle; it has no tense.  Many verbs have different forms for the p.p. and the past tense, for example *done* versus *did*; but in many more verbs the form is the same, and the two senses must be distinguished by their role in the sentence structure.

Participles are often used as adjectives: *a stolen car*, for example.  How did the car get that way?  It *was stolen* — not *was steal*.

Answer (score 1):

“will be asked” is future passive, and “are asked” is present passive.

Passive voice is formed by the helper verb “to be” in the desired tense followed by the past participle (-ed form) of the main verb.